# How add item to table with condition in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I have an issue when I'm going to add an item to a table row I need to set a condition on a field that when I want to add an item it should check the field and after that, it should check the sum of numbers in a table column and if it's greater than 100 it should not let the button to add an item.

```
void validateScorItem(int questionItem)
{
    var Sum = questionItem;
    foreach (var qItem in _Items)
    {
        Sum += qItem.QuestionItemWeight;
        if (Sum > 100)
        {
            Toaster.Error("Sum of numbers is greater than 100");
            isValidScore = false;
        }

        break;
    }
}


bool isValidScore = true;
void AddNewItem()
{
    validateScorItem(questionItem.QuestionItemWeight);
    if (isValidScore)
    {
        _Items.Add(questionItem);
        questionItem = new QuestionItemInfo();
    }
    else
    {
        isValidScore = false;
    }
}
```

the problem is when it throws a warning about the number that I can't add after clear the fields it doesn't work anymore and I can't add a new number.

Comment: It seems that once you reach 100, you wont be able to add any more item, that's exactly what your code is asking to do. So does it not work or just dont allow you to add more items?  Another point you have to check, is the break inside for each. It doesn't make much sense having a break without a condition.

Comment: This code was useful but just one thing wasn't correct and this is about (clear) remove all the items and I want to remove the last item that is false

Comment: If you want to remove only the last item.   _Items.RemoveAt(_Items.Count - 1);

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work but thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
//use bool as a return value to return if the current questionItem is valid or not
bool IsValidateScoreItem(int questionItem)
{
    var sum = questionItem;
    foreach (var qItem in _Items)
    {
        sum += qItem.QuestionItemWeight;
        if (Sum > 100)
        {
            Toaster.Error("Sum of numbers is greater than 100");

            //return false to signal it is invalid
            return false; 
        }
    }

    //return true to signal it is valid
    return true;
}

void AddNewItem()
{
    //check if it is valid or not
    if (IsValidateScoreItem(questionItem.QuestionItemWeight))
    {
        //if valid add it to the _Items list
        _Items.Add(questionItem);
        questionItem = new QuestionItemInfo();
    }
    else
    {
        //if invalid restart by clearing the "old" entries of _Items
        //or do nothing here if _Items gets cleared somewhere else
        _Items.Clear();
    }
}
```